# Hide part of text in input field

Tags: reactjs, security, input, passwords, show-hide

I using library `react-text-mask` for applying the mask to the input field. But now I get trouble because I should use a mask with two "-" and also hide text as a password. I tried to use CSS style: `-webkit-text-security: 'disc'` but this style hiding everything, even dashes. Also, I tried to use .replace for value but it's not a good idea because this method changes the value of the field. Maybe someone got a similar problem and know simple decisions or library for it.

[image: how it should looks like]

I also tried to implement it, but for now it's not working correct when items hidden.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-text-mask-testing-forked-vttdw

Comment: Please create a [mcve]